# AWS Network Load Balancer, Nginx, Too many redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

we are currently with 2 Nginx boxes taking requests directly from the web and are trying to set up an AWS Network load balancer in front of them. However, we keep getting the too many redirect issue...

I have done some research and follow a few instructions but it still does not work.
This is our current setup

Load balancer have 2 listeners on port 80 and 443
there is a certificate loaded on the load balancer and is managed by ACM

both direct traffic to a target group on port 80
the target group have 2 Nginx boxes with the following configuration

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  test.server.com;
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /etc/project/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection  "1; mode=block";

    location @app {
      add_header X-Frame-Options "";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
```

seem pretty standard to me but it does not work. the static files are served without problem but the @app block is not getting any request to the backend (unicorn).
Obviously, this is an updated configuration, my previous configuration has port 80 redirects to port 443 with proper SSL setup but since we have SSL on the load balancer now, we've removed it from here.

I've also tried setup a 443 port with SSL turned off but that does not seem to work with Nginx (the SSL is always on).

Comment: This nginx config doesn't do any redirects, so it's likely coming from your proxied app or elsewhere in your config

Comment: You are right @jordanm, It's the Rails configuration force_ssl that does it.Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off force_ssl = true in the environment. this will fix this, that flag does many things though so you might need to look at it and turn back the things that you want individually  (like Strict-Transport-Policy and secured session cookies)